# How to implement network calling , when the user is in another call and his call is not disturbed

Tags: android, agora.io

We are implementing network calling feature in Agora SDK. We are able to call to the other person but the call now gets merged with a network call that already exists. So how do we avoid that. If there is a possibility with Agora SDK android, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I made a network call feature similar to yours, currently I use `TelephonyManager` to detect the current state of the mobile calls:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = 
(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if(telephonyManager.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
   //proceed to initiate network call feature of AgoraSDK
} else {
   //Do nothing, or notify the other caller that the user is busy via API or Push.
}
```

Note that this only detect calls via mobile network, it will not detect other type of calls, for example, through Whatsapp, Viber, or Skype calls.